# Decodable JSONSerialization error custom object alamofire

Tags: swift, post, alamofire, codable

I have a custom APIClient using alamofire5 beta that conforms to Codable protocol for the request.
I'm trying to send a custom object via httpBody (post) and I'm getting this error:

> Invalid type in JSON write (_SwiftValue)

This is the object that I'm trying to send:

```
struct Complex: Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String
    var address: String
    var zipcode: String
    var amenities: [String]
    var schedules: [ComplexSchedules]

    init(id: String, name: String, address: String, zipcode: String, amenities: [String], schedules: [ComplexSchedules]) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.address = address
        self.zipcode = zipcode
        self.amenities = amenities
        self.schedules = schedules
    }

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id = "id"
        case name = "name"
        case address = "address"
        case zipcode = "zipcode"
        case amenities = "amenities"
        case schedules = "schedules"
    }

    struct TimeRange: Codable {
        var from: String
        var to: String

        init(from: String, to: String) {
            self.from = from
            self.to = to
        }

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case from = "from"
            case to = "to"
        }
    }

    struct ComplexSchedules: Codable {
        var day: String
        var timeRanges: [TimeRange]

        init(day: String, timeRanges: [TimeRange]) {
            self.day = day
            self.timeRanges = timeRanges
        }

        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case day = "day"
            case timeRanges = "time_ranges"
        }
    }
}
```

It fails when I call this method:

> urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: complex, options: [])

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need

```
do {

     let data = try JSONEncoder().encode(complex)
     urlRequest.httpBody = data
}
catch {

   print(error)
}
```

as `Codable` is used to be able to utilize `JSONDecoder` and `JSONEncoder` not to use with `JSONSerialization` that expects a non-custom object like raw `String/Array/Dictionary`

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm.

Comment: @Gerkor You can take a look at Alamofire's `feature/encodable-requests` branch for an in progress version that adds support for requests with `Encodable` bodies. Only JSON encoding is supported at the moment, but form encoding should come too.